# Actionscript 3 - how to capture data from one text area into another text area on a different frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Basically i am trying to capture data in a text area which is input from an XML file and then a few frames later get the text from that text area into another text area.

i have tried using `movietxt.text = txtarea.text;`but that doesn't seem to work.
another ive used is:
`txtarea.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changehandler);
function changehandler(evt:Event):void
{
movietxt.text = txtarea.text;
};`

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so what is the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know if this is possible and if so what is the code?

Yes, this is possible.

Store data in the frame where you capture text:

```
this.storedText = "some stored text";
```

Later, a few frames after, restore text:

```
movietxt.text = this.storedText;
```

Comment: This doesnt work for what i need if for unfortunately. il try and explain it a little better.
im trying to get the text from txtarea.text which is being entered from an XML file and then a few frames later bring that text forward into movietxt.text. e.g what movie would you like to see? [txtarea] (txtarea has information being entered from my XML file) then on a later frame. so the movie you would like to see is [movietxt] @Nicolas Siver

Comment: If information from the XML, what is еру problem to use XML in another frame?

Comment: im am asking the users a few different questions which are bought in from an XML file and then i want the answers to all be bought over to a summary screen.

Comment: So I don't get why my solution doesn't work for you. I assume you have some button that triggers script like `gotoAndStop()`, right before user leave current frame, store necessary texts from the fields